# Xaml files inside a shared project appearing differently in VS2017

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution, containing a shared project:

[image: Shared project]

This contains a number of Xaml files:

[image: Xaml files in VS2015]

However, when I open the exact same solution in VS2017, I get this:

[image: Xaml files in VS2017]

The problem seems to cause any XAML files to be invisible within the project.  The solution compiles and runs fine - is there something that needs to be installed or switched for VS2017 to treat shared projects correctly?

Comment: And VS is fully updated?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the hot key 'SHIFT + F7' to get the designer view? Or is the xaml file not readable at all?

Comment: It is fully updated, and shift F7 does nothing, presumably because the project doesn't understand it's a XAML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Solution
(1) Exclude 
(2) Show All Files
(3) Include all the files
Found some similar post may be work for you (seems to be some sdk needs to be installed)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26291339-e8fd-4596-980a-7befa63a1f7c/missing-folders-files-add-item-options-in-shared-project?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Thanks

Comment: Although this wasn't the exact solution, installing the Windows 10 SDK did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Visual Studio 2017 Installer, add support for Universal Windows Platform Development. That will connect each xaml to its respective xaml.cs in a shared project.

One would think that .Net Desktop Development would be enough to do the link, but it is not.